# Not able to read Json Object in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I am trying to parse a JSON object, as shown below, where the header object would be a random alpha numeric number.  Also, sometimes the JSON could contain only one object.

```
{
  "48ce0e9a-ee27-4e7b-93a5-4f219974f62c": {
    "preview": {
      "FRONT": "https://123avb.jpg",
      "INSIDE_TOP": "https://456ihn.jpg",
      "INSIDE_BOTTOM": "https://987ung.jpg",
      "BACK": "https://ikh980.jpg"
    },
    "print": {
      "primary": "https://iifuer.pdf",
      "secondary": "https://09e491.pdf"
    }
  },
  "d767e1a6-7afe-4d17-85f7-d512a0ca0b14": {
    "preview": {
      "FRONT": "https://0ff7cc7.jpg",
      "BACK": "https://64e7a8.jpg"
    },
    "print": {
      "primary": "https://73fbdc.pdf"
    }
  }
}
```

I created classes for these objects as:

```
namespace FulfillmentModel
{
    public class Baseclass
    {
        public G1 G1 { get; set; }

        public Env Env1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Preview
    {
        [JsonProperty("FRONT")]
        public string FRONT { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("INSIDE_TOP")]
        public string INSIDE_TOP { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("INSIDE_BOTTOM")]
        public string INSIDE_BOTTOM { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("BACK")]
        public string BACK { get; set; }
    }

    public class Print
    {
        [JsonProperty("primary")]
        public string primary { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("secondary")]
        public string secondary { get; set; }
    }

    public class G1
    {
        public Preview preview { get; set; }
        public Print print { get; set; }
    }

    public class Preview2
    {
        public string FRONT { get; set; }
        public string BACK { get; set; }
    }

    public class Print2
    {
        public string primary { get; set; }
    }

    public class Env
    {
        public Preview2 preview { get; set; }
        public Print2 print { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I am reading the JSON object from an API.
I am using the following code to convert it into a `BaseClass`:

```
string Jsontring= response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
var verificationResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Baseclass>(Jsontring);
```

but the object in the `BaseClass` is null.

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.  Can you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your JSON, there are keys `48ce0e9a-ee27-4e7b-93a5-4f219974f62c` and `d767e1a6-7afe-4d17-85f7-d512a0ca0b14` in the outermost object.  But these keys are not present in the `Baseclass` model class you are deserializing into, which contains `G1` and `Env` properties.  You could mark these properties with `[JsonProperty]` attributes, but since you said that these keys are random, the better way to handle it would be to deserialize into a `Dictionary<string, G1>`. (Alternatively you can use `Dictionary<Guid, G1>` if you are sure that the alphanumeric keys will always represent GUIDs).

```
var verificationResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, G1>>(Jsontring);
```

Now `verificationResult` will contain a dictionary, where the keys are the random keys from the JSON.  The values corresponding to each key will be a `G1` object, which has populated `Preview` and `Print` objects.

Demo fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/kzGihd

Comment: `Dictionary<Guid, G1>` would be better.

Comment: @PMExtra Perhaps. The OP did not say that the keys were Guids (though they do appear to be); just that they were "random alphanumeric numbers".  Given the loosey goosey specification, string keys are safer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add await before the async function?

await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()